# Better choice: Singleton or dispatch_once?

Tags: ios, memory-management, singleton, sprite-kit

I have a bunch of animations contained in about 10 texture atlases. The project I am working on has a bunch of bad guys running around so obviously I shouldn't duplicate all the animations each time a bad guy class is instantiated.

Should I use (option A) a singleton class to store ALL my bad guy animations and have it return a specific animation whenever needed to a bad guy class or do I insert (option B):

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
// do animating stuff here...
});
```

into my bad guy class? OR is this a case of tomato vs. tomatoe ?

P.S. I REALLY suck at working my own class methods so if option B is the answer, a working example would be oh so greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you use a real singleton or a shared instance is more or less the same in this example. that said you probably go better in other cases as testing if you have the ability to instantiate independent objects.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - when you get a moment, i'd appreciate you repeat your suggestion and dumb it down a couple of notches so I can understand it too.

Comment: There are tons of articles why singletons might bite your a** in testing, just google it.

Comment: If you make a strict singleton, one that overrides alloc. Then yeah it will be impossible, but I like to design my singletons as non singleton objects with a "shared" pointer so I can test it, (create individual instances for testing, but inject a shared in production) but can still leverage the singleton pattern where it makes sense. (Something like a data access layer entry point, or an object that wraps your core data stack, you probably only want one of these in production).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at Apple's [code:Explained Adventure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/BuildingtheWorld/BuildingtheWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140-CH3-SW10). At section "Loading Shared Character Assets", they use:

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    sSharedIdleAnimationFrames = APALoadFramesFromAtlas(@"Boss_Idle", @"boss_idle", kBossIdleFrames);
    // (Load other animation frames)
    sSharedDamageEmitter = [SKEmitterNode apa_emitterNodeWithEmitterNamed:@"BossDamage"];
    sSharedDamageAction = [SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:0.0],
        [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5],
        [SKAction colorizeWithColorBlendFactor:0.0 duration:0.1]]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Great link BTW. I never came across that before and it was very informative.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question of using a singleton vs dispatch_once, dispatch_once is not a singleton by itself, instead it is often used as a way of instantiating a singleton within the singleton accessor method. It will ensure that the block is only ever executed one time for a program's life. We can use this to ensure we only create our object one time.

Example

```
+(instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static MySingletonClass *s_sharedPointer = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(onceToken, ^{ // ensures we only ever create one MySingletonClass
        s_sharedPointer = [[MySingletonClass alloc] init];
    });
    return s_sharedPointer;
}
```

I am not as familiar with the nuances of Spritekit or animations, so I am unable to provide much detail regarding your specific problem, but I hope my answer provides some direction. Hopefully someone else who knows more about working with animations will answer with better insight on a good class design.